# Inkscape not opening after installed?

Tags: ubuntu, inkscape

I just installed 14.04 on my laptop. The first thing I did was to install `inkscape` by using the instructions on this [website](http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-latest-version-inkscape-in-ubuntu-14-04-or-linux-mint-17-via-ppa.html).

However, after installation, it does not appear if I search for it in the Unity dash. If I try running it from the command line, it says that it is not installed. But if I try to to install again, it says that the newest version is already installed. Additionally, Ubuntu Software Center says that it is installed.

See the terminal output below. What should I do?

```
    mark@kitchencomputer:~$ inkscape
    The program 'inkscape' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
    sudo apt-get install inkscape
    mark@kitchencomputer:~$ sudo apt-get install inkscape
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    inkscape is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to use the PPA?

Comment: Where is your executable? What does `dpkg -L inkscape | grep bin` give?

Comment: It returns /usr/bin. But when I actually look in that folder, there is no inkscape executable file in there! Also, `which inkscape` returns nothing. What could that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem was, but I found a solution.

Since my operating system is 64-bit, I went [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/inkscape) and downloaded the 64-bit deb package and installed that directly. Now the install works just fine.

I still don't know why it wouldn't have installed the correct version by using the command `apt-get install inkscape`?